# ломается сравнение строк в си

Tags: c, массивы, scanf

не знал как описать эту проблему в заголовке короче, поэтому звучит так нелепо. проблема заключается в следующем. есть такой простецкий код по проверке пароля:

```
    char code[6] = "passw";
    char input[6];
    scanf("%s",input);
    while(1)
    {
        if(strcmp(input,code) == 0)
            printf("correct\n");
        else
        {
            printf("not correct\n");
            
        }
        scanf("%s",input);

    }
```

все вроде работает норм, пока я не начинаю вводить больше 5ти символов. после этого мой ответ passw просто не принимает. в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы портите память. Чудо что после этого вообще что-то работает.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а можете подсказать, как решить этот казус? может какой то другой способ проверки?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy и почему именно после ввода большего количества символов чем 5 происходит такое,

Comment: Если вы введёте 105 символов, то первые шесть из них окажутся в массиве `input`. Остальные 100 и нулевой символ будут записаны в память после массива. Поэтому, когда вы вводите больше пять символов, всё что больше портит память рядом с массивом.

Comment: 1. Используйте `"%5s"` чтобы читать не более пяти символов. Тогда лишние символы останутся во входном потоке и позже будут портить вам жизнь. В этом случае надо прочитать и выбросить все символы до конца строки. 2. Читайте символы по одному и сверяйте с очередным символом пароля. Тут важно не вылезти за пароль и важно дочитать строки до конца даже если пользователь ошибся.

Comment: а зачем вы вводите больше 5 символов, если у вас массив всего на 5 символов?

Comment: [fscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf): "Note that %s and %[ may lead to buffer overflow if the width is not provided.". С - такой язык, что им невозможно пользоваться правильно не прочитав самым тщательным образом документацию.

Comment: @Эникейщик да на самом деле это вышло случайно, а потом просто стало интересно из за чего это происходит

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ясно, спс за ответ

Comment: На практике лучше использовать [getline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), а далее, если потребуется, разбирать строку самому